# Syntax for LINQ to DataSets Row Filter in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-dataset

I have two DataTables one is Primary Table and the rest is a sub table (I am using strongly typed dataset).

Example

**Employee Table**

```
Id   Name   City 
1    AAA    NY 
2    BBB    BB
3    CCC    AA
```

**CityInitials Table**

```
CityInitial
NY    
FF  
CC
RR 
RNF
YOT
DDD
```

I have to select rows from employee table only when the 'city' in Employee table matches any of the CityInitials of
CityInitials Table. i tried

```
var _filter = EmployeeTable.AsEnumerable().
Select(x=>x.Field<string>("City")).Contains
(CityInitials.AsEnumerable().Field<string>("CityInitials").Select(row=>row);
```

Please suggest what is the proper query to achieve the result?

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: you are quering data from database....

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know the join syntax. Wouldn't that be appropriate here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume these are in fact typed datasets? Without knowing exactly what you're working with, I'd call the following an approximation of what I'd expect to work:

```
var cities = CityInitials.Rows.Select(x => x.CityInitials).ToList();
var _filter = EmployeeTable.Rows.Where(x => cities.Contains(x.City));
```